# Meteor: How can i push items to users collections and create a list or array instead of replacing each item with the new one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to attach objects from another collection to the Meteor.user collection by a click event. I have a collection with a list of items called "categories" each category has a name field, its that name i want to push into the meteor.user.

Its supposed to work in a way that the user can push as many of these names as they want however its only accepting one entry, and when i click on another name, the new name replaces the old one, instead of being an array. how can i make it so that it can allow many entries?

client/users.js

```
Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .toggle-category': function(e){
          //var id = $(e.target).attr('posts.name');
          var id = $(e.target).parent().find("a").text();
          console.log(id);

          e.preventDefault();
          Meteor.call('addingCategory', id, function(error, user){ console.log(id)});
      }
});
```

server/users.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    addingCategory: function(name) {

      var cats = [{}];
      cats.push(name);
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    }, {
      $set: {

        name: name
      }
    });
    }
});
```

and this is the user from db.user.find() as you can see with

> **"name" : "a-reece"**

its clearly pushing the name but i cannot add more, i can only replace

> { "_id" : "4CHcZjSD4hCrqweGA", "createdAt" :
>   ISODate("2016-07-13T21:38:59.505Z"), "services" : { "password" : {
>   "bcrypt" :
>   "$2a$10$lKZtrYSMD4EGPj6eamgFDuPZ41Jw52DgivBly3lUYWbGDtfZBg1X." },
>   "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ { "when" :
>   ISODate("2016-07-13T21:38:59.719Z"), "hashedToken" :
>   "BsqTGedB2FkmSPO3+5I31rOM2+MPtF97Zc9tRQ4pf8Y=" } ] } }, "emails" : [ {
>   "address" : "mun@les.com", "verified" : false } ], "roles" : [
>   "discoveror", "yes" ], "isAdmin" : true, **"name" : "a-reece"** }

how can i add more names instead of replacing?

> EDIT

```
Meteor.methods({
    addingCategory: function(name) {

        //Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $addToSet: { name: name} } );
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        //Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { "categories": cats }} );
        Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    },
      {
        $unset: {
            name: name
        }
      },

    {
      $addToSet: {

        name: name
      }
    });
    }
});
```

> ANSWER

```
 Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .toggle-category': function(e){
          //var id = $(e.target).attr('posts.name');
          var ob = $(e.target).parent().find("a").text();
          var id = $.makeArray( ob );
          console.log(id);

          e.preventDefault();
          Meteor.call('addingCategory', id, function(error, user){ console.log(id)});
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently doing:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $set: { name: name } });
```

You have two choices: `$push` or `$addToSet`:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $push: { name: name } });
```

or

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $addToSet: { name: name } });
```

The former pushes onto an array, allowing duplicates, the latter avoids dupes.

You don't need:

```
var cats = [{}];
cats.push(name);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding @MichelFloyd. when i use £addToSet i get the following error  **$addToSet to a non-array field. Field named 'name' has a non-array type String in the document _id:**

Comment: That's because you've already `$set` the field previously as a string instead of an array. You'll have to `$unset` any such fields first.

Comment: Do you mean in the methods? please look at my EDIT at the bottom of the question. i did it this way, but there are no errors in the console nor terminal yet nothing was added to the user. Please advise @MichelFloyd

Comment: You can't unset and addToSet in the same update statement. Because you've already seeded your database with non-array elements you should go through and convert them to arrays first (a one-time operation), then just use $addToSet from then on.

Comment: Yes thank you. I made it into an array first, then i did $addToset. it worked. I appreciete all your help @MichelFloyd

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd you have helped me with the complex parts of my application dealing with $in operator. could you help me with this problem that has been plaguing me for months [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329030/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-a-complex-manner-between-3-collections)

Comment: It looks like it in the first instance, but that solution I already have as the second step in my process, I have updated the question to further drill down my problem. Please take a look. @Michel