# Creating a many to many relationship in a complex manner between 3 collections

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collections

I have 3 collections, `meteor.user()`, `Categories` and `Posts`.

A user can choose to follow any category's posts by saving the id of the category in an array in `meteor.user()`

The end goal of this is that the user has a Personal stream where **only** the posts in the categories they are are following show up.

Each post inside the `Posts collection` has within it an array of the Categories it's featured in.

[image]

and each category has within it an array of posts, each post in the array has a field of `ID` of the post.

[image]

Where `id: 67` is the id of the category, and `posts.ID: 74` is the id of a post within the category.

below is the id of the post in Posts collection with matches posts.ID in the category collection

[image]

The User saves a category id so it appears as the category array in meteor.user()

[image]

When I do this

```
Template.userTimeline.helpers({
  category: function() {
    var posts = Category.find({
      id: {
        $in: Meteor.user().category
      }
    });
    return posts
    console.log(posts);
  }
});
```

I can do this

```
 {{#each category}}
  <ul class="article-timeline">
    {{#each posts}} {{ID}} {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

But this lets me access the posts.ID within the category collection and display it.

### PROBLEM

How can I go further and match posts.ID I got with the above code, to the the id of a post in `Post` so that I can access the posts from the `Posts` collection. Could i do something like this?

```
Template.userTimeline.helpers({
  category: function() {
    var postsInCategory = Category.find({
      id: {
        $in: Meteor.user().category
      }
    });

    var postMatch = Post.find({
      ID: {
        $in: postsInCategory
      }
    });
    return postMatch
    console.log(postMatch);
  }
});
```

### FURTHER EDIT AFTER ZIM ANSWER

So the solution you have given me is taking `post.title` from the post object **contained within** my `Categories` collection as shown below.

[image]

This `post` array within the `Category collection` is incomplete, its a copy of an original `Posts Collection`

what I need to do is use `post.ID` as shown in the image above. i.e. the post array within the Categories Collection, to create a *many to many relationship* with the `id` of a post within the original `Posts` Collection so, instead of having `post.title` I need to have `title.rendered` as below.

Posts Collection.

[image]

If you see that the `ID` (not the top id, which is the id of the category), `post.ID` in the post array within the Categories collection is **IDENTICAL** to the `id` of the post in `Posts` collection. This is the crux of it all, help me create a relationship so that, instead of displaying `title` or `post.title` from the post array **within** the `Categories` Collection, I need to display `title.rendered` within the original `Posts` Collection.

Comment: I humbly suggest you put entire schema into different collections. All data will be exposed on the client side, which is very dangerous. You rather make respective collections and then you make a common field to map each entry. You really don't need to make things so complex as the internal relations can work out like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203584/how-to-display-children-of-publish-composite-collection-on-template-view You can simply loop data inside templates with the help of helpers and subscriptions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. @AnkurSoni It's complex, I haven't defined a schema, the data is coming through json as a post from WordPress. Hense why I'm going this.

Comment: what is your question? :)

Comment: Instead of displaying posts.ID in the template, how can I match posts.ID within the category collection, to its exact match in Posts, which is the post id, so that, instead of showing the data of the posts coming from the category collection, I can display data from the Post itself, through matching the ids @AnkurSoni

Comment: I already gave you the link. Look into the answer. It explains everything that you just asked. Stay cool minded, relax and read the answer. I too once had this question, solution is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you don't control the data format, so you would have to use a nested loop to deal with the format you have. i think the following should work.

```
Template.userTimeline.helpers({
  categories: function() {
    return Category.find({
      id: {
        $in: Meteor.user().category
      }
    });
  }
});
```

note i changed the name of your helper.

```
{{#each category in categories}}
  {{category.description}}
  {{#each post in category.posts}}
    {{post.title}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

c.f. http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in

*EDIT:*

ideally, you would be able to do a server-side join using a package like https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

but since you don't have control over that, you can do a client-side join. you would do this in the onCreated() of your template (caveat: this is untested!)

```
this.subscribe('posts', function() {
    let cursor = Categories.find({id: {$in: Meteor.user().category}});

    cursor.observe({
        added: function(newDocument) {
            let category = newDocument;

            // for this category, get all the associated post ids
            let postIds = _.map(category.posts, function(p)) {
                return p.ID;
            };

            // get the posts. we can fetch these because we waited for the publish of the posts collection.
            let actualPosts = Posts.find({id: {$in: postIds}}).fetch();

            // attach the actual posts to the category
            category.actualPosts = actualPosts;
        },
        changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument)  {
            // if wanting to track changes to the categories, similar to added block
        }
    });
});
```

then with a simple change to the template, you can grab those actual posts:

```
{{#each category in categories}}
  {{category.description}}
  {{#each post in category.actualPosts}}
    {{post.title}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

doing the client-side joins is a little more tricky, because as the above is written, you're missing reactivity to the user's tracked categories, and posts w/in the existing categories. so you could further put all that in an autorun. that would track changes to Meteor.user().category, but not sure if that would track post changes w/in the categories. but this should get you a lot of the way there.

*EDIT 2:*

oh yeah, if you do it that way, that listener will stay active when the template goes away unless you call stop() on it. so...

```
Template.userTimeline.onDestroyed(function() {
    let handle = this.observeHandle.get();

    if (handle) {
        handle.stop();
    }
});

Template.userTimeline.onCreated(function() {
    let self = this;
    self.observeHandle = new ReactiveVar();

    self.subscribe('posts', function() {
        let cursor = Categories.find({id: {$in: Meteor.user().category}});

        let handle = cursor.observe({
            added: function(newDocument) {
                let category = newDocument;

                // for this category, get all the associated post ids
                let postIds = _.map(category.posts, function(p)) {
                    return p.ID;
                };

                // get the posts
                let actualPosts = Posts.find({id: {$in: postIds}}).fetch();

                // attach the actual posts to the category
                category.actualPosts = actualPosts;
            },
            changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument)  {
                // if wanting to track changes, similar to added block
            }
        });

        self.observeHandle.set(handle);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Please take a look at the further edit to explain exactly what I need. Long story short, I am already getting post.title successfully, but the problem is that it's coming from the post array in the  Categories collection instead of the Posts collection. Please take a look at the edit for further explanation @zim

Comment: @ShingaiMunyuki, understood. i'll update my answer w/ a client-side join.